# Can we download multiple CSV files from a website using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to create a dataframe containing Australian public holidays for last 5 years.
I am planning on using this [webpage](https://data.gov.au/data/dataset/australian-holidays-machine-readable-dataset) to retrieve the data as it contains yearly CSV files since 2014.
Unfortunately, the URL link to each file uses different naming structure which makes it hard to create a dynamic URL name for looping.
For example (*please refer to the bold sections*):
2020 dataset = data.gov.au/data/dataset/b1bc6077-dadd-4f61-9f8c-002ab2cdff10/resource/**c4163dc4-4f5a-4cae-b787-43ef0fcf8d8b**/download/australian_public_holidays_2020.csv

2021 dataset = data.gov.au/data/dataset/b1bc6077-dadd-4f61-9f8c-002ab2cdff10/resource/**2dee10ef-2d0c-44a0-a66b-eb8ce59d9110**/download/australian_public_holidays_2021.csv

```
import pandas
from datetime import date

# First section of URL
url1 = 'https://data.gov.au/data/dataset/b1bc6077-dadd-4f61-9f8c-002ab2cdff10/resource/'

# Second section of URL
url2 = 'MISSING PIECE'

# Third section of URL
url3 = '/download/australian_public_holidays_'

# Variable date section of URL
period = date.today().strftime('%Y')

# Last section of URL
url5 = '.csv'

# Create URL
url = url1 + url2 + url3 + period + url5

# Display URL
url
```

Since I am unable to identify the pattern of the unique (bold) section, I am thinking of downloading all the files from the parent URL and then union/append all data into a single dataframe.

All ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
import requests

req = requests.get(url)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('downloaded.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

With this piece of code, you will download the data to a .csv file. You can use it with Python by open it with Pandas, or take this downloaded data to another program.

Comment: Thank you, @Diego.

Since I need to use this for work, the **re.content** did not work due to proxy.
However, I tried your code off VPN and got confused as the **.write()** returned 61334 - not sure what that meant.

Is there any solution that can skip proxy?

Comment: As a workaround to skip proxy, using Python, I have been downloading CSV or XLSX files in my download folder, then get data from those files to dataframe.